Nav bar slow to load using separate file
I have my nav bar HTML in its own file. It's simple a href text with a 60KB image. I'm calling it with this at the bottom of my body:
  <script>
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
  </script>

I've looked at the Network console and the nav.html is executed well after a few other files.
I tried adding the nav.html code directly to the main index.html, and this latency is gone.
I only have two pages, so I might hardcode it if I can't figure out why this latency is happening. I'm using php -S to run on a localhost.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Why not just require it into the file? <?php require('path_to_file.html'); ?> Unless you need the asynchronous loading?

@quietWind01 i will probably try this or just hardcode it, thank you!
